# Simplifying a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I searched around a lot but I am currently stumped. I am looking to simplify an array so it's a little easier to work with ...

Right now my array looks like this:

```
[[{"title"=>"Test Entry 2", "date"=>"2013-11-01 21:05"}, "\nThis is just another test entry."], [{"title"=>"Test Entry", "date"=>"2013-11-01 18:05"}, "\nThis is just a test entry."]]
```

And to print these values I currently have:

```
entries.each do |x|
  puts x[0]["title"]
  puts x[0]["date"]
  puts x[1]
end
```

I would like it to look like this (I think):

```
[{"title"=>"Test Entry 2", "date"=>"2013-11-01 21:05", "content"=>"\nThis is just another test entry".}], [{"title"=>"Test Entry", "date"=>"2013-11-01 18:05", "content"="\nThis is just a test entry.}]
```

I'm looking to be able to call these values easily with a loop, something like:

```
entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry["title"]
  puts entry["date"]
  puts entry["content"]
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for looking!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
a = [[{"title"=>"Test Entry 2", "date"=>"2013-11-01 21:05"}, "\nThis is just another test entry."], [{"title"=>"Test Entry", "date"=>"2013-11-01 18:05"}, "\nThis is just a test entry."]]

a.map! {|hsh, content| hsh['content'] = content; hsh }

#=> [{"title"=>"Test Entry 2", "date"=>"2013-11-01 21:05", "content"=>"\nThis is just another test entry."}, {"title"=>"Test Entry", "date"=>"2013-11-01 18:05", "content"=>"\nThis is just a test entry."}]
```

This works b/c the `map` block can take multiple arguments which are assigned in index order of the array. So `map` iterates over the `a` array, pulling out each hash and content string. We then assign the content string to a new `content` member of the hash and return the hash.

Comment: That does add the "content" value but leaves the ", "\nThis is just another test entry" at the end. Thanks.

Comment: I added the output I get from the code above to the answer. Not sure exactly what you are referring to.

Comment: Ahhh I see the problem. My mistake, I was assuming that you would just use the return value of `map`. Switch the call to `map!` to modify the array in place

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help Alex. Sometimes I just can't figure out where to look.

Answer (score 0):

You've already did it. After correcting a small mistake, you are getting following

```
entries=[
  {"title"=>"Test Entry 2", "date"=>"2013-11-01 21:05", "content"=>"\nThis is just another test entry."},
  {"title"=>"Test Entry", "date"=>"2013-11-01 18:05", "content"=>"\nThis is just a test entry."}
]

entries.each do |entry|
  puts entry["title"] # Test Entry 2
  puts entry["date"]  # 2013-11-01 21:05
  puts entry["content"] # 
                        # This is just another test entry.
end
```

Just a Array of Hash(es). You can also display values with `entry.keys.each {|k| puts entry[k]}` expression.